# Try to list two year cost in one table error Can not get result

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get 2016 and 2017 average cost group by agencyname. But I cannot get the result and I am not sure the error.  Thanks for the help.

The table is

```
 Agencyname  Agencyid   Timesheetcost   projectyear
   companya  1          500             2016
   companya  1          600             2016
   companyb  2          700             2017
   companyb  2          800             201[7][1]
```

output want to be

```
   agencyname   agencyid    2016_averagecost    2017_averagecost    
   companya     1           500                 600 
   companyb     2          700                  800
```

Query is:

```
select a.AGENCYNAME,a.projectyear,avg(a.timesheetcost),b.AGENCYNAME, b.projectyear,avg(b.timesheetcost)from table a, table b
where a.PROJECTYEAR = 2017 or b.PROJECTYEAR=2016;
group by a.AGENCYNAME,b.AGENCYNAME;
```

Comment: You need to add to your question: the table schemas, sample data, and an example of the result. The query is not only wrongly writter form a syntax point of view, but also the condition doesn't make sense. In the where clause you should have some relation between a and b to avoid a cartessian product between a and b.

Comment: Hey Juan,Just add a sample data and sample output I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with correlated sub-queries. Assuming your table is called "costs", you can do:

```
select agencyname,  
     (select avg(c.timesheetcost) from costs c where a.agencyid=c.agencyid and c.projectyear=2016) as 2016_averagecost, 
     (select avg(d.timesheetcost) from costs d where a.agencyid=d.agencyid and d.projectyear=2017) as 2017_averagecost
from costs a
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I aslo find out use case statement works as well/